# Emulator Keyboard does not appear Codename one

Tags: keyboard, emulation, uikeyboard, codenameone

I have a project where when i try to type in the textbox, the keyboard appears and my text box shrinks, have gotten a way of preventing the text box from shrinking due to the answer Shai gave me on the google forum, but i can not test it in my emulator because the keyboard does not appear in emulator, how can i make the emulator keyboard to appear please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't since its implemented natively on the device we can't reproduce it in the simulator.
However to test a screen resize you can switch a simulator skin or rotate the simulator using the menu options which will produce a similar effect.